# Counting specific words within a batch of Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, script, vba, automation, vbscript

I need  a count of the number of times an acronym (e.g. ‘ABC’) is used in a collection of word documents. The acronym is always three letters and in block caps.

All the word documents are contained in the same folder.

What is the easiest way to do this? Using a VBS script?

Comment: I have successfully run this script to count the acronyms occuring in a single word document: http://word.tips.net/T001833_Generating_a_Count_of_Word_Occurrences.html

Comment: How could I make this script search through all word documents in a folder and return the total count for the acronym across all documents?

Answer (score 1):

If they're uncompressed (i.e. not DOCX format), any file-search tools, such as Windows *[find](http://www.howtogeek.com/206097/how-to-use-find-from-the-windows-command-prompt/)* can count them. If they're in Zip compressed format, the free *[Agent Ransack](http://mythicsoft.com/agentransack/download)* can search within the files, as well as in uncompressed documents. It shows a summary with counts, as well as the name of each document with the search string and each line containing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following VBS code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.GetFolder("c:\")
For Each thing in f.files
    If LCase(Right(thing.path, 3)) = "doc" Then
        Set doc = GetObject(thing.path)
                For each wd in doc.words
                    If wd = "cat" then Counter = Counter + 1
                Next
                Doc.close
                set doc = nothing
    End If
Next
MsgBox Counter
```